# android studio: duplicating files even when using exclude fix

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble building my app all of a sudden.

the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task  
Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86_64/libogg.so

File1: C:\Users\name\.android\build-cache\72c018be052ae391eef4ab43483d6a04be10a818\output\jni

File2: C:\Users\name\.android\build-cache\425f82e82c18acce2ff0ced2ade670804d31a815\output\jni
```

I have attempted to fix using packaging options:

```
 packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

entire file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myappsid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.9.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':library-release')

}
```

any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried longer exclude options as well in other posts that I have found but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `pickFirst` in **packagingOptions**. You need to get the correct package name of `libogg.so` from **File1** or **File2**:

```
packagingOptions {

   pickFirst 'com/library/name/lib/x86_64/libogg.so'

   ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

There is a conflicted dependencies:

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.4.2'
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.9.1'
```

From the [Watson Developer Cloud Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) documentation you can find the following:

> The Android SDK utilizes the Java SDK while making some
>   Android-specific additions. This repository can be found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk). It
>   depends on OkHttp and gson.

which is pointing to the first library. So, you should only use:

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.4.2'
```

Comment: I did try that and it worked however now I'm getting same issue just different files.

Comment: It looks like because of those library: `compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.9.1'`

Try to use only one of them.

Comment: Thank you, turns out that was the issue.

Comment: Congratulations! Glad it help you ;)